# SWIG : Error: Unable to find 'stdexcept'

Tags: swig

I use SWIG to create some C# wrappers, but it seems that I got a set of errors, even after including the corresponding .i libraries!

%module test_module

```
%include <stl.i>
%include <windows.i>
%include <typemaps.i>
%include <stdint.i>
%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_vector.i>
%include <inttypes.i>
%include <attribute.i>
%include <cpointer.i>
%include <exception.i>
%include <carrays.i>
%include <cdata.i>
%include <cmalloc.i>
%include <constraints.i>
%include <cpointer.i>
%include <cwstring.i>
%include <intrusive_ptr.i>
%include <math.i>
%include <pointer.i>
%include <std_except.i>
%include <swigarch.i>
%include <swigrun.i>
%include <wchar.i>
%include <shared_ptr.i>

%{
  #include "Context.hpp"
%}

%feature("nspace") Context;

%include "Context.hpp"
```

and here is the list of errors :

```
core\Expected.hpp(18) : Error: Unable to find 'memory'
core\Expected.hpp(19) : Error: Unable to find 'utility'
core\Expected.hpp(20) : Error: Unable to find 'typeinfo'
core\Expected.hpp(21) : Error: Unable to find 'exception'
core\Expected.hpp(22) : Error: Unable to find 'stdexcept'
core\Expected.hpp(23) : Error: Unable to find 'type_traits'
core\Definitions.hpp(22) : Error: Unable to find 'inttypes.h'
core\Definitions.hpp(23) : Error: Unable to find 'type_traits'
core\Definitions.hpp(24) : Error: Unable to find 'stddef.h'
core\Definitions.hpp(25) : Error: Unable to find 'stdint.h'
core\EnumBitMaskGenerator.hpp(18) : Error: Unable to find 'type_traits'
core\PImpl.hpp(20) : Error: Unable to find 'type_traits'
core\PImpl.hpp(21) : Error: Unable to find 'memory'
core\PImplSizes.hpp(18) : Error: Unable to find 'vector'
core\PImplSizes.hpp(19) : Error: Unable to find 'deque'
core\PImplSizes.hpp(20) : Error: Unable to find 'fstream'
core\PImplSizes.hpp(21) : Error: Unable to find 'memory'
core\PImplSizes.hpp(22) : Error: Unable to find 'map'
core\PImplSizes.hpp(23) : Error: Unable to find 'mutex'
core\PImplSizes.hpp(24) : Error: Unable to find 'atomic'
concurrency\ThreadLocalPointer.hpp(20) : Error: Unable to find 'thread'
concurrency\ThreadLocalPointer.hpp(21) : Error: Unable to find 'unordered_map'
```

And here the command line, with the options:

swig.exe -includeall -c++ -csharp -macroerrors -cppext cpp ...

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using -I to set the include path. See:
http://swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn2

Answer (score 0):

It seems like *.i files from the SWIG/Lib are quite useless and provided as a kind of stub. You have to add SWIG/Lib/csharp as SWIG include dir instead.